# Finding Quantiles and Sampling from a Mixture of Distributions

Tags: distributions, quantiles, weibull-distribution, extreme-value, pareto-distribution

I am trying to replicate a result in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aoas/1520564474), specifically I am trying to implement the mixture distribution on page 9 of the document.

The authors describe a hazard function:
$$
h(x):=h_{1}(x) \eta\left(\frac{x-u}{\varepsilon}\right)+h_{2}(x)\left(1-\eta\left(\frac{x-u}{\varepsilon}\right)\right)
$$
where
$$
\eta(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
{1,} & {x \leq 0} \\
{2 x^{3}-3 x^{2}+1,} & {0<x<1} \\
{0,} & {x \geq 1}
\end{array}\right.
$$
and
$h_1(x) = \kappa\beta^{-\kappa}x^{\kappa-1}$ is the hazard function of a Weibull distribution, and $h_2(x)=(\sigma+\xi(x-u))^{-1}$ is the hazard function of a Generalized Pareto distribution.

Essentially we have a Weibull distribution for $x \le u$, a Generalized Pareto distribution for $x \ge u+\epsilon$, and some weighted mixture of the two for $u < x < u+\epsilon$.

The overall distribution function is then
$$
F(x)=1-\exp (-H(x))=1-\exp \left(- \int_{0}^{x} h(z) \mathrm{d} z\right)
$$

I would like to generate samples from this distribution. My initial plan was to to figure out $F(x)$, generate $p \sim Unif(0,1)$ and then generate a sample by computing $F^{-1}(p)$. However, the integrals become unwieldy when trying to calculate the distribution directly, and I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach. The authors never mention their sampling method, and I couldn't find any more information on sampling in the references for this part of the paper.

If anyone has any insight on how you might compute quantiles and generate samples from the distribution described here, I'm all ears.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a purely numerical approach?
If you ignore completely the structure of the hazard function, there is a standard way to generate samples from an arbitrary hazard function:
Using the fact that $u = F(x) = 1 - \exp(-\kappa) = 1- \exp(-\int_0^x h(z) dz$ is $~U(0,1)$, as you write, you can calculate $\kappa = - \log(1-u)$ (or $-\log(u)$) and then by numerical integration solve for $\kappa = H(x) = \int_0^x h(z) dz$.
The fact that you can analytically integrate to get $H(x)$ can help you numerically, even if you are not able to invert the function analytically.

Comment: As far as I understand this mixture is only used for illustration of the proposed method. An alternative illustration could be obtained by using a standard mixture as provided by  the **evmix** CRAN R package.